# Why CPP file name must tally with H file name?

Tags: c++, eclipse

First thing first, sorry for asking such a stupid question. I just find it interesting and I was so curious to know why. I have a base class with virtual destructor declare in Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_

class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
};
#endif
```

And then I have a Child class inherited Base class declare in Child.h

```
#ifndef CHILD_H_
#define CHILD_H_

#include "base.h"
class Child : public Base {  // (1)
    public:
        Child();
};
#endif
```

Now make a `main.cpp` and put in the implementation of Base class virtual destructor.

```
#include "Base.h"

Base::Base() {}
Base::~Base() {}
```

The source code was compiled using Eclipse C++ Kepler in Ubuntu 13.04. There is an error complaining that `undefined reference to 'Base::Base()'` at **(1)**. If I **change main.cpp to Base.cpp**, the error will gone.

May I know why this could happened? Is this due to the configuration in Eclipse? If it is, can I turn off this feature? Or is this due to the best programming practices so that the source code much more manageable? Or is this a C++ specification?

Answer (score 1):

There's no specification in the standard that this shouldn't work, nor do I think eclipse enforces this layout. It is indeed more manageable and common, but by no means a requirement.

You probably didn't add `main.cpp` to the build and it's not getting compiled.

Comment: Further, if you use multiple source files for the implementation of a class, such a restriction is impossible to meet.

Answer (score 1):

This has *nothing* to do with the C++ specification.  It must be in Eclipse, perhaps in the makefile.  You could always factor out a simple single line to run from main.cpp (along with `#include`'s) to keep there and put the rest in Base.cpp.